# WordPress wp_link_pages Foreach

Tags: wordpress

I want WordPress post pagination. So, using `wp_link_pages()` in a `foreach` statement, how can I do it?

```
foreach(wp_link_pages() as $page){
    echo $page; 
}
```

The above code is not working

**I solved**
include the php file

```
global $page, $pages;
print_r($pages);
$total_page = count($pages);
$current_page = $page;
```

Thanks!

Comment: can't echo a page

Comment: What do you want to do with your code? May ther's another way to do this.

Comment: I do a gallery with page break so I do try pagination foreach.

Answer (score 1):

As you can read in the [wordpress docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_link_pages/), wp_link_pages() returns a HTML-formatted string:

> **Return #**
>   *(string)* Formatted output in HTML.

PHP's foreach requires an array to loop trough.

Comment: I solved include the php file

global $page, $pages;
print_r($pages);
$total_page = count($pages);
$current_page = $page;

Comment: Glad tk hear that. Happy new year :)